# Joining together two tables to use the value from one table in a query where there is a unique identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry, I've had to edit the main post to fit everything in.

I'm trying to build a query from multiple different tables.

Currently I have an output from this query::

```
select 
    opt.oper_type, oc.card_number, op.account_number,
    opt.oper_currency, opt.session_id, opt.part_key,
    opt.msg_type, op.auth_code, opt.oper_date, 
    opt.oper_amount, opt.oper_currency, op.customer_id, 
    clearing_sequence_num, clearing_sequence_count 
from 
    opr_operation opt, opr_participant op, opr_card oc 
where
    op.oper_id = opt.id
    and op.participant_type = 'PRTYISS'
    and oc.oper_id = opt.id
    and opt.msg_type in ('MSGTPAMC', 'MSGTPACC');
```

Output:

```
OPER_TYP    CARD_NUMBER ACCOUNT_NUMBER  oper_currency   opt.session_id  opt.part_key    opt.msg_type    op.auth_code    opt.oper_date   opt.oper_amount op.customer_id  clearing_sequence_num   clearing_sequence_count
1           12345678910234  12345678910234        1            12345    270324            MSG            123456           250324    3000             12345678                   1                  2
```

But, I also want to include a further column called `oper_amount` as 'Local Amount' which is taken from another table called `VIS_MESSAGE.oper_amount` and `oper_currency` as 'Local_Currency' also from `VIS_MESSAGE.oper_currency`. To link the 2 records together, they both have the same unique `auth_code` on the VIS_MESSAGE table and op.auth_code table and the same date oper_date on the VIS_MESSAGE and opt.oper_date tables.

So something along the lines of

```
select 
    opt.oper_type, oc.card_number, op.account_number,
    opt.oper_currency, opt.session_id, opt.part_key,
    opt.msg_type, op.auth_code, opt.oper_date,
    opt.oper_amount, opt.oper_currency, op.customer_id, 
    clearing_sequence_num, clearing_sequence_count 
from 
    opr_operation opt, opr_participant op, opr_card oc, **oper_amount & oper_currency from VIS_MESSAGE 
where 
    auth_code = op.auth_code 
    and oper_date = opt.oper_date 
    and oper_amount as 'Local Amount' 
    and oper_currency as 'Local_Currency' **
    op.oper_id = opt.id
    and op.participant_type = 'PRTYISS'
    and oc.oper_id = opt.id
    and opt.msg_type in ('MSGTPAMC', 'MSGTPACC');
```

So that the output would be similar to below

```
OPER_TYP    CARD_NUMBER ACCOUNT_NUMBER  oper_currency   opt.session_id  opt.part_key    opt.msg_type    op.auth_code    opt.oper_date   opt.oper_amount op.customer_id  clearing_sequence_num   clearing_sequence_count   Local Amount  Local Currency
1           12345678910234  12345678910234        1            12345    270324            MSG            123456           250324    3000             12345678                   1                  2            1234             2
```

Sorry, thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`  statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the problem that uses the same table and column name (not `table1` and `table2` which does not match your query); and the expected output for your query (as text, not as an image).

Comment: "I'm trying to build a query from 2 different tables." Your query uses 3 tables so which two are the ones you are expecting to use?

Comment: As said in the first comment, [edit] your question and provide a [MRE] with the appropriate `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data so that we can see full details (including the relational constraints between the tables) and also include the expected output for that sample data (as text, not as an image).

Comment: [**Bad habits to kick**: using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Yes apologies @marc_s - I don't profess to be an SQL expert and just trying to knock up something quick and dirty to give me some info in a test environment. If I can't do it then there's no harm done.